# Testing for Named Enchanted Items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I’m working on a named sword that makes something happen when you hold it.

The sword is enchanted, but it seems my code isn’t working. Is there a specific thing I need to add if the sword is enchanted and named?

My current code is:

```
execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_sword",tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Escargot"}'}}}}]
```

Comment: What is your current code? We need to have something to work off of in order to give an appropriate answer for you.

Comment: My current code is /execute as @a{SelectedItem:{id;”minecraft:iron_sword”,tag:{display:{Name:’{“text”:”Escargot”}’}}}}] run say hi

Comment: It appears that your question is a duplicate of [this one](/questions/384468/) so we're closing this. In the end, it's also a bad practice to test for custom item names, so you really should consider switching.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it wasn’t working, my sword had italics in it’s name and I forgot to mention that in the command block that’s testing for it